# Understanding the possible values of orbital angular momentum of an electron orbiting a magnetic flux tube

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, anyons

I am reading through the paper Magnetic Flux, Angular Momentum, and Statistics by Frank Wilczek (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.48.1144) and had some questions about parts (B) and (C) as labeled in the paper.

**The setup:** We consider a particle of charge $q$ that orbits a solenoid whose magnetic field runs along the $z$-axis. Outside the solenoid, the magnetic field vanishes but the magnetic vector potential $A$ does not neceessarily vanish. Rotations around the $z$-axis are generated by the (covariant) angular momentum $l_z = -i\partial_\varphi -qA_\varphi$. In a nonsingular gauge, $A_\varphi = \Phi/2\pi$ and the azimuthal dependence of the electron wave function is $\psi_n \propto e^{in\varphi}$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $l_z\psi_n = (n - q\Phi/2\pi)\psi_n$, i.e. the angular momentum of the electron is quantized in units $l_z = n - q\Phi/2\pi$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We can then perform a gauge transformation to remove the potential outside the solenoid, namely, $\vec{A}' = \vec{A} - \nabla \Lambda$ with $\Lambda = \Phi\varphi/2\pi$. This is singular because $\varphi$ is a multivalued function.

**Questions:**

1. Why are we only dealing with orbital angular momentum here (as opposed to total angular momentum)? What is covariant angular momentum?
2. Why is $l_z = -i\partial_\varphi - qA_\varphi$?
3. How do we know what the electron wave functions look like? In particular, how do we know that they are eigenfunctions of angular momentum? Do we just need to solve the time independent Schrödinger with the Hamiltonian associated to this system? Or can we concoct some sort of symmetry argument?
4. Why is $\vec{A}'$ singular? Is it because $\varphi$ is multivalued that $\vec{A}'$ is also multivalued? Hence, it is singular in the sense that it has elements in its domain that are not sent to a well-defined point in its codomain?